# trying using a bash script in wsl with cd but it doesn't do anything

Tags: scripts, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cd

I have created the following script just for learning bash script in wsl saving as Desktop.sh in nano

```
#!/bin/bash 
cd /mnt/c/Users/myusername/Onedrive/Desktop
```

when i am in the shell and type bash Desktop.sh

nothing happens

Any advice would be helpfull
thans

Comment: why should something happen? You have nothing in there that should show anything? If nothing is shown that is expected. `cd` will only show something if there is a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script, which you invoked with the command `bash Desktop.sh` worked perfectly, but you do not see any effect.

Why?

Because the script is run in a subshell.

Executing the script with `bash Desktop.sh`will start a subshell, and run any command within the subshell. Thus, the current directory is changed in the subshell, and only in the subshell. When the script stops, you return to your shell, where nothing has changed. The same happens if you made the script executable, them run it by typing its  pathname. In that case, the shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) is read to determine which shell to load.

To *see* an effect, you instead need to perform the `cd` command in the *current* shell. You can do so by *sourcing* the script:

```
source Desktop.sh
```

or with a shortcut notation:

```
. Desktop.sh
```

Now, the effect is as if you would have typed the commands in the script on the prompt yourself.

Comment: thank you , very much since i m a new to this i didn't know the source command